# FMU execution using GPU

Tags: gpu, fmi

I'm currently doing simulation using FMI.
Due to performance issue I'm looking for a solution to execute the FMI on GPU.

Does a solution exist in order to directly execute FMI on a GPU (high level) ?

Regards

Comment: Probably nothing off the shelf. What authoring environment are you using to produce the FMU? Maybe it is possible to get the FMU to execute faster by removing/reducing/simplifying some of the dynamics in it...

Comment: Why do you want to use GPUs and what do you hope to gain? (i.e. what takes time...)

Comment: Why GPU : 
I have few models (around 100) executing in paralell. My idea was to use the GPU in order to host part of them,

Comment: Origin of my FMU : divers : Matlab, C Code, Dymola, Amesim, ....